@firebase/app-check: FirebaseError: AppCheck: ReCAPTCHA error
I implemented the App Check reCAPTCHA Enterprise process in my javascript web application. I followed everything mentioned in the document. Enabled the AppCheck in the Firebase console, registered the web app, and enabled the reCAPTCHA Enterprise API in the GCP console. Created the site key and added that key in the Firebase app check console. Added the dependencies in my project and wrote code for AppCheck.
The issue is when running the code in localhost, I added the below line to run in localhost as the document says. It's working fine
self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;

When I deployed the code, I removed that line and deployed it. After removing that line getting the below errors. What am I missing?
    @firebase/app-check: FirebaseError: AppCheck: ReCAPTCHA error. (appCheck/recaptcha-error).
        at ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider.getToken (providers.ts:173:22)
        at async getToken$2 (internal-api.ts:156:42)
        at async Promise.all (index 1)

    Error getting documents:  FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

I am adding the code of my js file below and I am calling this file my HTML file using module type.
var key  = "SITE-KEY-HERE"
        
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.2/firebase-app.js';
import { getAuth, signInWithPhoneNumber, RecaptchaVerifier } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.2/firebase-auth.js';
import { getFirestore } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.2/firebase-firestore.js';
import { collection, getDocs, addDoc, Timestamp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.2/firebase-firestore.js"
import { query, orderBy, limit, where, onSnapshot } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.2/firebase-firestore.js"
import { getMessaging } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.2/firebase-messaging.js';
import { initializeAppCheck, getToken, ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.12.2/firebase-app-check.js';

var firebaseConfig={
    apiKey:"API-KEY",
    authDomain:"deyapaylive1.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL:"https://SOME.firebaseio.com",
    projectId:"PROJECTID",
    storageBucket:"SOME.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId:"ID",
    appId:"......"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize other Firebase services
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const messaging = getMessaging(app);

// self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;

// Initialize App Check
const appCheck = initializeAppCheck(app, {
    provider: new ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider(key),
    isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: false
});

export { app, db, collection, getDocs, Timestamp, addDoc };
export { query, orderBy, limit, where, onSnapshot };

export { auth, messaging, appCheck, signInWithPhoneNumber, RecaptchaVerifier };

Security rules of particular doc

my HTML code
    const q = query(collection(db, "PhoneAuthdeyaPayUsers"), where("PhoneNumber", "==", userphonum));
    
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    
        if (doc.exists) {
           console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
           var FailedACHTransactionsCount = doc.data().FailedACHTransactionsCount;
           var AccountStatus = doc.data().AccountStatus || "Active";                           
        }
  });


Are you trying to retrieve any firestore documents? if so, can you share yours firestore rules ?

@RoopaM I added my security rules and HTML code.

For Phone authentication can you try using auth.token variable or get(), if you are trying to match field values in other documents. Also if possible, can you share your Firestore collection structure

@RoopaM Here, I need to access the document even before the auth. Based on the conditions, I will navigate the user to Firebase phone number auth or custom OTP auth.

Can you share your firestore structure? Meanwhile, have a look at this troubleshooting steps.

My document structure is
/PhoneAuthdeyaPayUsers/{PhoneNumber}/
{"Number" : "Userphonenumber",
"timestamp" : "",
CustomOTP" : ""
}
here document "PhoneNumber" and filed value "Userphonenumber" will be same

Have you tried troubleshooting steps mentioned in the above link?
